# Outdoor Light Electrical Spliced Nightmare

Tags: electrical

I am having my outdoor retaining wall redone and noticed this. [image: Electrical Line to Lamp Post]

I've done splicing of lines before but would like to ask what would be the best way to waterproof a clean splice? I know this looks like an extension cord but both sides are Romex. Should I leave it alone? This was done about 25 years ago when the old wall was installed and I recall that the contractor had problems with this working before. Yeah this is a hack job and something I wouldn't ever do myself. I honestly don't get how some people live with themselves and do this kind of mess that could cause a fire.

Comment: If it is romex then it cannot be outside anyway.  When you replace it with the proper outdoor/wet cable, you do away with the splice anyway.  Easy.  I bet if you remove the tape, you will find romex that has been made into an extension.

Comment: Yeah, it's Romex so it's ruined anyway. Try putting GFCI on the supply end and it'll just trip because of the water damage.

Comment: What voltage is this light? For 12V landscape lighting it's still horrible, but not horribly unsafe, for example.

Comment: It's standard 110V

Comment: Once you replace that cable and in the the future find a need to do splicing, there are a few different types of water proof splices.

Comment: What the heck is its purpose?

Comment: Are you sure that's Romex?  Are the markings legible?